# PHP: Why does else-block not work?

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input id="delete" name="delete" placeholder="Name" type="text"></b>
    <input type="submit" name="deleteButton" value="Go!">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['deleteButton'])) {
    $temp = $_POST['delete'];
    $deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM `berater` WHERE `Nachname` LIKE '$temp' OR `Vorname` LIKE '$temp' OR CONCAT(Vorname,' ', Nachname) LIKE '%$temp%'";
    $searchSQL = "SELECT FROM `berater` WHERE `Nachname` LIKE '$temp' OR `Vorname` LIKE '$temp' OR CONCAT(Vorname,' ', Nachname) LIKE '%$temp%'";
    $search = mysqli_query($db_link, $searchSQL);
    $loeschen = mysqli_query($db_link, $deleteSQL);

    if (!$search) {
        echo "Kein Datensatz gefunden!";
    } else {
        echo "$temp erfolgreich gelöscht.";
    }
}
```

I am new to PHP and thought the `mysqli_query` returns `false` if the name is not found in the database. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: false is about errors, otherwise you have to check result object.

Comment: you can select nothing and that can be a successful search

Answer (score 1):

According to [**mysqli_query() documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on **failure**. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a **mysqli_result object**. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Replace `if (!$search)` with `if (mysqli_num_rows($search) > 0)` to check if such row existed.

---

*By the way, this code can not be used in production: it is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I advise you to read this article before working with the database: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php*

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mysqli_num_rows`:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($search)==0) {
    echo "Kein Datensatz gefunden!";
} else {
    echo "$temp erfolgreich gelöscht.";
}
```